# Oracle SQL: all_tab_columns not returning valid tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have statement...

```
SELECT table_name from all_tab_columns;
```

Which returns...

```
X
```

When I attempt...

```
SELECT * FROM X;
```

I get...

```
Table DNE
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: You may not have permissions to access the schema in which the table resides.  But you may have permissions to see all objects in all schemas.  or you may need to prefix the X with the schema name in which it resides.  Who are you logged in as and who is the owner of the table in question? Consider: `Select Owner, Table_name, user  from all_tab_Columns;`  if owner <> user, you may need prefix or you may be lacking permission.

Comment: It might be permissions. I'm getting a different user for X in particular.

Comment: So if you change your query to query `Select * from owner.X` (where owner is the actual value returned not just 'owner') and you still get DNE then it's likely  a permission issue  Now if you get results, and you don't want to prefix the table name, then a synonym could be created in which X points to Owner.x and thus you dont' need the prefix.

Comment: Selecting Owner.X was the solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `Table DNE`? Is that the data in the table?

Answer (score 0):

Although your case may be different, in my particular case the issue was that the table `X` had a different `Owner`.

To access this, I used the command

`SELECT Owner, Table_name FROM all_tab_columns`

With the new User information, change your query to

`SELECT * FROM Owner.X`

Now, you should be able to select said table.